Is there a way to manage / read ACEs with Dynamic Access Controls?
So I have a windows server that has Dynamic Access Controls (claims-based access control entries or central access policies) on the ACEs. As far as I know I can only read it out on the security descriptor directly?
Does anyone have knowledge on how to do that and how to translate it in something "useful" in C#?
